# How to select double digit numbers from a column and change their format?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

So I have this dataset where the rating ranges from 0 to 5 and here there are double digit ratings, meaning that there must have be a decimal point between the two digits. Now the problem is that the column consists of single as well as double digit numbers and if I try to divide the numbers by 10 then it will also change the single digit numbers into decimal which I dont want.

Is there any way that I can just select the double digit numbers from this column and divide them by 10 to show them as decimal numbers?

I have tried to give a glimpse of the problem that I am facing(since I cant post an image of my data yet) but I hope you all can understand what I am trying to convey

How the Rating column looks like:
Rating
5
4
36
45
87

How it should look like
Rating
5
4
3.6
4.5
8.7

Comment: Oh yes it worked. I was actually trying with LEN()=2 but somehow it didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the length and divide by 10 if greater than 1:

```
=A1/10^(LEN(A1)>1)
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner This actually worked. However I didn't understand the solution very well. What does "^" actually do here? coz I have usually used ^ for powering up the numbers

Comment: `(LEN(A1)>1)` will return a 0 or a 1.  0 if it is false.  1 if it is true.  10^0 = 1 and 10^1 = 10.  So the number gets divided by 1 if it is 1 number and 10 if it is greater than 1.